# Add mysql DB on ubuntu container

Tags: php, mysql, apache, ubuntu, dockerfile

I would like to add my mysql database to my Dockefile running ubuntu with installed mysql and php. The folder is structured in this way:
     folder
       |_ Dockerfile
       |_ start.sh
       |_ index.php
       |_ init.sql

the problem is that start.sh don't exec all of my code, so the init.sql is not imported in mysql. I have looked some solution on StackOverflow but no one of them worked.

this is the Dockerfile

```
FROM ubuntu:latest
RUN apt-get update && apt-get upgrade -y
RUN DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install apache2 php libapache2-mod-php php-mysql mysql-server -y 
VOLUME ["/var/lib/mysql"]
ADD init.sql /tmp/init.sql
COPY index.php /var/www/html/
COPY start.sh /bin/
RUN chmod +x /bin/start.sh
EXPOSE 80 3306
CMD "/bin/start.sh"
```

This is the start.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

/usr/sbin/apache2ctl -D FOREGROUND
/usr/bin/mysqld_safe
mysql -u root -e "CREATE DATABASE mydb"
mysql -u root mydb < /tmp/init.sql
```

I'm not sure the problem is exactly start.sh, anyway every docker-compose solution will be useless for me since i need everything in a Dockerfile

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first you must reorder sequence in you `start.sh` , because apache in foreground will prevent you to run mysql .

```
#!/bin/bash
chown -R mysql:mysql /var/lib/mysql /var/run/mysqld && /etc/init.d/mysql start
while [ ! -e /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock ]
do
    sleep 2
done
mysqladmin ping

mysql -u root -e "CREATE DATABASE mydb"
mysql -u root mydb < /tmp/init.sql

/usr/sbin/apache2ctl -D FOREGROUND
```

and you must modify your `Dockerfile` to add :

```
RUN mkdir /var/run/mysqld ; chown mysql.mysql /var/run/mysqld
```